# Insert NULL variable into database

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have variable set to NULL that im trying to insert into a database but for some reason they keep getting submitted as '0'. Im positive that column im trying to inset into allows NULL and that the default is set to to NULL. Heres my code:

```
$insert = NULL;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` (column1) VALUES ('$insert')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Try to put default value as NULL in database table. When you create a new record column1 will be NULL automatically. Or try to set $insert variable as null $insert = null. And the question is - why you need it as NULL?

Comment: Have you tried using a prepared statement?
See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329542/php-mysql-insert-null-values][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329542/php-mysql-insert-null-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ### Warning:
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

**IF** you want it to be `NULL` (and you **really *really*** still want to use `mysqli_*`) in the database you can do the following:

```
$insert = NULL;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` (column1) VALUES ("
                         .(($insert===NULL)?
                                 "NULL":
                                 "'".mysql_real_escape_string($insert)."'").
                     ")") or die(mysql_error());
```

#### But this could lead to nefarious SQL injection and is **not** recommended.

See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

---

So: all in all you **should be using prepared statements**.

You can use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) like so:

```
        $dbHandle = new mysqli(...);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `table1` (column1) VALUES (?)";
        $statement = $dbHandle->prepare($query);
        if($statement){
            $statement->bind_param('s', $insert);
            if(!$statement->execute()){
                echo "Statement insert error: {$statement->error}";
            }
            $statement->close();
        }
        else {
            echo "Insert error: {$dbHandle->error}";
        }
```

Comment: Im talking about the first one

Comment: @JonahKatz are you sure that it is on the mysql_* line?

Comment: are you missing a semi colon at the end of a line somewhere

Comment: -1 for not fixing the SQL injection vulnerability in the first example. A warning is no excuse for leaving insecure code...

Answer (score 1):

Try this for static query:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` (column1) VALUES (NULL)")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Using Variable :

```
$insert= NULL;
$insert = ($insert===NULL)? 'NULL' : "'$insert'";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` (column1) VALUES ($insert)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That works, but i need it to be a variable because sometimes the variable isnt null

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes;

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` (`column1`) VALUES (".$insert.")") or die(mysql_error());
```

The query should be;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`column1`) VALUES (NULL);

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '., '24')' at line 1`

Comment: Well it works on my server... so you must be typing something incorrectly