# Associative array insert to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array...

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 10
    [code] => KA
    [rol] => B
    [pr] => 
)
```

what I want is when I insert to the MySQL all the empty array key filled with NULL...

here is what I tried...

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if (empty($value))
        $value .= NULL;

    else
        echo $value;
    }
```

or in different way...like this..

```
$value = implode("', '",array_values($array));
$val = ($value == ' ') ? NULL : "$value";
```

and insert to table..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('$val')";
```

But it seems I am not getting the NULL value in my fields...
what did I do wrong?

In short, how do I add Null to the empty array key...[pr]???

Comment: Is the column in your table allowing null?

Comment: yes,...That is the problem? If I don't have NULL in the empty field it crushes..

Comment: first step: learn what's PDO. Second step: learn what are prepared statements in PDO. Third step: ????????. Fourth step: profit!

Comment: Could it be a scope issue??

Comment: You will need to prepare your statement. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329542/php-mysql-insert-null-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$sql = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    $sql[] = empty($value)?'NULL':"'".addslashes($value)."'";
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES('.implode(",", $sql).')';
```

echo $value; will not help you if you want to use it as a query.

But:
Don't do it!
Use prepared statements instead.

Example:
http://codepad.org/lZfgVwIL

Comment: that is the echo from query.....INSERT INTO table VALUES('','','','','NULL','NULL','NULL','') as you see all the value are lost....some thing wrong?

Comment: @MR.Test probably your php version doesn't include mysql_real_escape_string() another reason to use prepared statements.

Comment: @MR.Test Edited my post and created an example on codepad. Should work now. If you still need this than your using prepared statements the wrong way. They are meant to seperate query and data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use double quotes `'NULL'` or `'null'` instead of `NULL`.

```
$val = ($value == ' ') ? 'NULL' : $value;
```