# SQL Server: NULL Concatenation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to construct INSERT sentences from a query like below:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (value1,value2);
```

So I do:

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (', value1, ',', value2, ');')
FROM OneTable
```

The problem I have is that sometimes, value1 may be NULL so in the result I need to obtain things like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (NULL,5);
```

how can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329542/php-mysql-insert-null-values

Comment: Why not use sp_executesql with proper parameters?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to `INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) SELECT column1, Column2 FROM OneTable`. I don't understand why you want to concat this... as long as `Field2` is `NULLABLE`, you don't need `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`

Answer (score 3):

Change your value1 to this

```
Coalesce(value1, 'NULL')
```

But I think you should use sp_executesql and provide parameters for it.

Comment: Is this approach preferable to using `ISNULL` and if so, why? Is there a functional difference between `COALESCE(value1,'NULL')` and `ISNULL(value1,'NULL')`?

Comment: For that, you can refer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828641/sql-difference-between-coalesce-and-isnull